# Load DATE type to Google BigQuery with Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

**Context**

I'm fairly new to the **Google Cloud Platform** and I'm trying out **Google Dataflow**. I read a CSV file and simulate streaming data. CSV row publishes into topic (PubSub) and **Dataflow** reads it and inserts the data into a BigQuery table.

**Problem**

When my file contains types STRING, FLOAT, INTEGER my process finished successfully and data is loaded to BigQuery. But if I add to my process one of those types: DATETIME, TIME, DATE it always fails. There are many code examples but I didn't find code example that show how to handle it.

**Data Examples**

`2017-01-23` - load it into DATE type

`14:10:12` - load it into TIME type

I hope you guys can help me with this ...

Comment: Please provide more details about your code and a complete printout of the failure. Merely knowing that the pipeline fails is insufficient to help you with debugging.

Comment: We use timestamp as date format in BQ.
While adding data to BQ from dataflow we are putting date as String with specific timestamp format yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss.SSS.  This is working perfectly for us in all pipes we build. Hope this will help

Comment: So, did you found which POJO to send to BigQuery for Date and DateTime formats ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried few things:

```
//1
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String dateInString = info.getEventDate();
  Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

row.set("EventDate", date);


//2
row.set("EventDate", new DateTime("2017-01-23")); 


//3
public String getEventDate() {
return get(Field.EventDate);  }
...
...
...
row.set("EventDate", info.getEventDate());


//4
private static DateTimeFormatter dmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
....
....
....
DateTime ds = dmt.parseDateTime(info.getEventDate());
```

Comment: Please provide the a full printout of the error message you're getting. It's unclear what part of your code is failing. Does the failure reproduce if you execute the DateTime parsing code on your local machine outside of Dataflow?

Comment: Hi Scott , Thanks for your response. code to large for sharing here.  I send you LinkedIn invitation. I will sent you by email.

Comment: Please send to dataflow-feedback@google.com instead.

Comment: Hi Scott , I send email with same post subject - Load DATE type to Google BigQuery with Dataflow

Comment: @HaimB were you able to resolve your issue? If so it is recommended to post the solution as the answer to better help the community. If not it is recommended to update your original question with a snippet of the error you are encountering.